# Extract folder from a .zip file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I want to download a folder using a [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) script, but I can't upload folders, so i decided to upload a `.zip` file.

The problem is that I want to extract the folder from the `.zip` file using a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file).

Answer (score 1):

In older `PowerShell` versions:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory("C:\file.zip", "C:\output")
```

Please note that you got to have `.NET 4.5+` installed and it will NOT overwrite existing files (will throw an error if file exists).

In `PowerShell v5+` you could simply use:

```
Expand-Archive C:\file.zip -DestinationPath C:\output
```

You can use relative paths in here as well.

Comment: 3.0+ for sure, not sure about 2.0, as there is no documentation on microsoft site

Answer (score 0):

Expand-archive is very basic.  I'm not above using the command line version of 7zip, like for extracting specific folders.  All you need is 7z.exe and 7z.dll.